# Identify task: Input polygon into IdentifyParameters

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I wish to find all the features within a polygon/circle drawn by my user.

May I know if I should use IdentifyTask

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/identifytask.html

Or is there a more recommended way?

Use Case: User drawn a circle/polygon and it will display all the address within the area.

Comment: Are all the features within a single layer in the mapservice?

Comment: yes, apparently identifytask only return a feature...any help on this?

Comment: The Identify task allows you to specify which layers in the mapservice you are interested in, whereas the Query task is for a particular layer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use QueryTask.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/querytask.html

It accepts a Query

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/query.html

which the a geometry parameter can be input to search for features within the specified criterias.

Using QueryTask.execute(parameters,callback,errback) method. It will return a feature set on onComplete(featureSet) callback.

which contains a property call features

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/featureset.html.

By looping through the features[]. We can get the set of features within the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the geometry using the identifyparameters class: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/identifyparameters.html

It will accept any type of geometry, typically you would pass it a point, but you could pass in a polygon that is drawn on the screen.

Comment: yes but apparently it only return a feature. I am trying to find all the address within a geometry.

Comment: It returns an identifyResult, not a feature: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/identifyresult.html

Comment: An identified feature. - yes 1 feature only.

Comment: I don't think you understand.  The identify result does not return a single feature, it returns a identifyresult, which is an object that contains an array of features.  The identifytask can query multiple layers and return features from these layers.  Perhaps you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/identifyresult.html

in the properties you will see "feature" only. It will return a single feature.

What I need is queryTask.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/querytask.html

which returns a featureset

Comment: The IdentifyTask does not return only one feature. For example, take a look at this sample that utilizes an IdentifyTask: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/find_drilldown.html Click on the border of two parcels and you'll get the two features. As you zoom out and click on the map, you'll get more and more features returned in the two visible layers.

Comment: The identifytask complete event (https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/identifytask-amd.html#complete), which is called after identifyTask.execute is called returns IdentifyResult[], which means an array of identifyResults.